# Flex2gateway not working on https/ssl on websphere

Tags: ssl, coldfusion, websphere, coldfusion-11

We are upgrading our ColdFusion 9 non-ssl application to ColdFusion 11 ssl enabled setup using Websphere.

We have a few flex components that utilize Flex2Gateway to call remote services. The application/Flex2gateway calls work fine with http but not on https.

The following urls give me a blank page which as per Adobe forums mean that Flex2Gateway is setup right:

```
http://example.com/flex2gateway
https://example.com/flex2gateway
```

The app calls the non-ssl url(not sure why):
    http://example.com/flex2gateway and then gets redirected to 
    https://example.com/flex2gateway

When I look at the browser developer tools(IE, Chrome) the redirection from

```
http://example.com/flex2gateway to https://example.com/flex2gateway
```

seems to be working fine. Can anybody provide some insights on a possible solution?
Here is my remoting-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<service id="remoting-service" 
class="flex.messaging.services.RemotingService" 
messageTypes="flex.messaging.messages.RemotingMessage">

<adapters>
    <adapter-definition id="cf-object" 
class="coldfusion.flash.messaging.ColdFusionAdapter" default="true"/>
    <adapter-definition id="java-object" 
class="flex.messaging.services.remoting.adapters.JavaAdapter"/>
</adapters>

<default-channels>
    <channel ref="my-cfamf-secure"/>
</default-channels>

 <destination id="ColdFusion">
    <channels>
        <channel ref="my-cfamf-secure"/>
    </channels>
    <properties>
        <source>*</source>
    </properties>
 </destination>
```

I do see the following in services-config.xml and I did uncomment the WebsphereLoginCommand option but saw no difference.

```
<security>
    <login-command class="flex.messaging.security.JRunLoginCommand" server="JRun"/>
    <!-- Uncomment the correct app server
    <login-command class="flex.messaging.security.TomcatLoginCommand" server="Tomcat"/>
    <login-command class="flex.messaging.security.WeblogicLoginCommand" server="Weblogic"/>
    <login-command class="flex.messaging.security.WebSphereLoginCommand" server="WebSphere"/>
    -->
```

**UPDATE**: I got https disabled on our server and receive the below error now when I try to access flex component:

```
faultCode:Client.Error.MessageSend faultString:'Send Failed' faultDetail:'Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed:url: 'http://example.com/flex2gateway/"
```

Comment: nothing stands out - but what is your flex code doing? Which of the two is it contacting?

Comment: @MarkAKruger updated. The flex code calls http and then gets redirected. I tried finding the source but could not find the invocation point.